# Cannot compile bibliography on texmaker

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

i am trying to write my thesis but i cannot compile the bibliography, these are the packages and syntax I used.
The error message i get is:

> Citation 'xxx' on page 'nnn' undefined

How do i fix this issue? I am using a .bib file with all references listed there.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{book}
%
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.xmpdata}
    \Title{Master Thesis: bla bla}
    \Author{Myself}
    \Language{en-GB}
    \Subject{...}
    \Keywords{...\sep}
\end{filecontents*}
%
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{colorprofiles}
\usepackage[a-2b,mathxmp]{pdfx}[2018/12/22]
\hypersetup{pdfstartview=}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, right=2cm, left=2cm, bindingoffset=0.9cm, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xmpincl}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,]{biblatex} % <<<----- my biblography style
\addbibresource{06_references.bib}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small}
%
\begin{document}

\onehalfspacing
\input{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\frontmatter

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{3}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\nouppercase{\textit{\leftmark}}}

\chapter*{Abstract}
\label{chap:abstract}
\input{00_abstract}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nameref{chap:abstract}}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}  
\input{01_introduction}

\chapter{Aim of the thesis} 
\input{02_aim}

\chapter{Materials and methods} 
\input{03_materials}

\chapter{Results and discussion} 
\input{04_results}

\chapter{Conclusions}  
\input{05_conclusions}

\begingroup % <<<------ my bibliography is here
\setstretch{1}
\setlength\bibitemsep{5pt}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: did you run biber? What does the blg-file says?

Comment: I did select biber in the texmaker configurations panel. I don't know where to find the blg file.

Comment: Is the last comma here needed? What if you delete that? \usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,]{biblatex} Change it to this, and see if it works? \usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}